# What is the mean about "mysql+pymysql" in flask

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to use MySQL in flask, and one config is

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db"
```

If I use `mysql+pymysql`, it can work

But when I only use `mysql`, the erroe message like this

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

But in my code, I don't import  `pymysql`, so what is the `pymysql` and why need use that can work

> I know `pymysql` is a moudle

Thanks your reply!

Comment: Please specify which database client are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `create_engine` function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html) (which is what uses the URL given in the config), requires you to give it a "dialect". [A "dialect" is the name of the underlying database engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/index.html) that SQLAlchemy is connecting to.

However, since many databases have multiple different clients (in Python these implement DBAPI), so in many cases ([such as for the mysql dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html)) you're required to give the name of the client you want SQLAlchemy to use. In this case, you're asking it to use the `pymysql` library to actually handle connectivity with MySQL.

SQLAlchemy 1.3 supports the following dialect/DBAPI-libraries for connecting to MySQL:

- mysqlclient (maintained fork of MySQL-Python)
- PyMySQL
- MySQL Connector/Python
- CyMySQL
- OurSQL
- Google Cloud SQL
- PyODBC
- zxjdbc for Jython